# ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->addSubscriberService() always throws ClassNotFoundException in a Service

Tags: php, events, symfony, dependency-injection

**This is my error:**

> **ClassNotFoundException:** Attempted to load class "EventSubscriber" from the global namespace in /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php line 143. Did you forget a use statement for this class?

**Problem Story:**

Ok so i read about the awesome `ContainerAwareEventDispatcher` and how i can add a `Service` as a subscriber. Man would i love to do just that.

Problem is, i seem completely unable to do just that.

I must say that when i read the Docs i immediately wondered where i should instantiate the `ContainerAwareEventDispatcher`. I decided i would place it inside a `Service` constructor and made a service called `CentralDispatcher`, seemed logical to me to make the dispatcher itself accessible inside a service.

After i encountered the ClassNotFoundException when i tried to do the above:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher;
use aktn\Bundle\Events\ProjectEvents;
use aktn\Bundle\Service\EventSubscriber;

class CentralDispatcher {

public function __construct() {

    $container = new ContainerBuilder();
    $dispatcher = new ContainerAwareEventDispatcher($container);

    $dispatcher->addSubscriberService(
        'EventSubscriberService',
        'EventSubscriber'
    );

    $dispatcher->addListenerService(ProjectEvents::EVENT_INITIALIZE, array('EventSubscriberService:', 'onInitialize'));
}
```

I decided i should try placing the constructor code inside a Controller to see whether it was something i did not understand yet (though this question will probably imply exactly that), so i tried this:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher;
use aktn\Bundle\Events\ProjectEvents;
use aktn\Bundle\Service\EventSubscriber;

 class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {


    $container = new ContainerBuilder();
    $dispatcher = new ContainerAwareEventDispatcher($container);

    $dispatcher->addSubscriberService(
        'EventSubscriberService',
        'EventSubscriber'
    );

    $dispatcher->addListenerService(ProjectEvents::EVENT_INITIALIZE, array('EventSubscriberService:', 'onInitialize'));

    return $this->render('DefaultBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

But i encountered exactly the same `ClassNotFoundException` :(

THEN i started to lose my confidence and tried to insert the 'actual' `Service Container` with my `EventSubscriber` Service into the `ContainerAwareEventDispatcher`.

Same error.
Even though i asserted whether the service was in the container or not with the `$container->has('EventService');`
It returned `TRUE`.

I have absolutely no clue of what to do, and i would love to make progress.
Untill i know, i'll refrain from using the `ContainerAwareEventDispatcher` and try to build around using it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using this inside Symfony or as a separate component? If you are using it inside Symfony then isn't this already available using the tags in the services files through the DI.

Comment: Yeah inside Symfony, it is indeed available inside a controller with the tag `'debug.event_dispatcher'`.
But the same thing happens, whichever Service id and Class name i pass to the `addSubscriberService` method, the same Exception gets thrown..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have been able to work around the issue for a week, just started looking into it again.

Solved it by passing the whole namespace instead of just the classname to the addSubscriberService function, like so:

```
$dispatcher->addSubscriberService(
    'EventSubscriberService',
    'vendor\EventBundle\Service\EventSubscriber'
);
```

The docs read that the argument was the Service's class name.
I will note this and in the near future propose a change in the docs by forking it on Github.